# How to change path to site-packages dir in easy_install

Tags: python, windows-7-x64, easy-install

I'm trying to use easy_install on windows7x64 and getting this:

```
<output>
c:\Python27\Scripts>easy_install.exe django-piston
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\Lib\
\site-packages\\test-easy-install-4132.pth'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Lib\site-packages\

This directory does not currently exist.  Please create it and try again, or
choose a different installation directory (using the -d or --install-dir
option).
```

Where can I change easy_install's path to correct one "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages"?

Answer (score 10):

easy_install should install the packages in the Python installation's site-packages directory. It could have happened that you changed Python's directory accidentally.
Reinstalling easy_install should fix this.

Otherwise you could use:`easy_install --install-dir C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Lib\site-packages\ django-piston`

However, this last option has two issues:

1. Make sure `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Lib\site-packages\` is in PYTHONPATH
2. You will need to indicate a install-dir directory for every new package you install

Comment: Can you please add `distribute`?